# Does it matter if a class is abstract when it uses Generics?

Tags: c#, generics, abstract-class, abstract

I.e, does the `abstract` modifier do anything here:

```cs
public abstract class MyClass<T> where T : class {
}
```

You can't use Generic classes on their own anyway, so what difference does it make if it's `abstract` or not?

Comment: Do you have any problem?

Comment: [`abstract`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/abstract) has no relation to [generics](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/generics/)

Comment: An empty abstract class could be used in the same way an empty interface is used - as a flag that the extending or implementing class is being used for a special purpose.  The interface would be a better choice though.  Other than that, I agree with @Herohtar that `abstract` indicates the class is a kind of template - and `generics` which make the class, well, generic, have two different purposes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the `abstract` keyword, you have to subclass it to use it.

```
class MySubclass : MyClass<string>
{
}

var o = new MySubclass();
```

Without it, you can instantiate directly:

```
var o = new MyClass<string>();
```